# Using NSTimer to call SetNeedsDisplay in Xamarin for iOS

Tags: c#, objective-c, nstimer, xamarin, setneedsdisplay

I have a UIView that takes data (thats changing) from a buffer and plots it.  I want the screen udpated at 10Hz.  The UIView is called pane, and this is how i'm invoking it inside the ViewController:

```
        //create graphics to display data
        GraphPane pane = new GraphPane ();
        pane.Frame = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
        Add (pane); 

        //setup timer to update pane
        NSTimer timer = NSTimer.CreateRepeatingTimer (0.1, delegate {pane.SetNeedsDisplay ();});
```

This isn't working (Pane.Draw is never called), and I've not found a good example of how to do this.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Is `timer` deallocated when it goes out of scope?

Comment: I actually have timer defined as a class variable so it shouldn't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
        timer = NSTimer.CreateRepeatingScheduledTimer (TimeSpan.FromSeconds (0.1), delegate {
            pane.SetNeedsDisplay ();
        });
```

fixed my issue.

Comment: The change was from CreateReapeatingTimer to CreateRepeatingScheduledTimer - seems it isn't scheduled by default.